# Spring Cache -- ClassCastException (ehcache)

Tags: java, spring, ehcache

I have a problem, when I try to get a list of data from cache.

**CategoryServiceImpl:**

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class CategoryServiceImpl implements CategoryService {
@Resource
private CategoryRepository categoryRepository;

@Override
@Caching(
        put = {
                @CachePut(value = "category", key = "'findByParrentId-' + #category.parentId + ',' + #category.user.userId"),
                @CachePut(value = "category", key = "'findAll-' + #category.user.userId")
        }
)
public Category add(Category category) {
    return categoryRepository.saveAndFlush(category);
}

@Override
@Cacheable(cacheNames = "category", key = "'findByParrentId-' + #prntId + ',' + #userId")
public List<Category> findByParentId(long prntId, long userId) {
    return categoryRepository.findByParentId(prntId, userId);
}

@Override
@Cacheable(cacheNames = "category", key = "'findAll-' + #userId")
public List<Category> findAll(long userId) {
    return categoryRepository.findAll(userId);
}
}
```

When I try to get a list of categories:

```
List<Category> categories = new ArrayList<>(categoryService.findByParentId(parentId, userSession.getUser().getUserId()));
```

I get an exception:

> ClassCastException: ru.mrchebik.model.Category cannot be cast to java.util.List

Full stack trace: http://pastebin.com/35A14ZW9

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the cache named "category" is configured to hold Category elements :

```
@CachePut(value = "category", key = "'findByParrentId-' + #category.parentId + ',' + #category.user.userId")
```

and then you expect this same cache to return List :

```
@Cacheable(cacheNames = "category", key = "'findAll-' + #userId")
```

I think you want your cache to store `List<Category>` ; so instead of putting Category , you should put `List<Category>` when you try to warm up your cache.

Comment: it works, but I give only one element. What I must to do, if I want to give all elements? Now, I have this: `public List<Category> add(Category category) {
categoryRepository.saveAndFlush(category);
List<Category> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(category);
return list;
}` I can to create a local variable of List, but this is not the cache.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve does not work with the Spring caching abstraction. You have to do more by hand to get the result you want.

First of all, there is now way with Spring caching to express that a single element needs to be added to a collection in the cache. So you need to maintain the content of the mappings yourself.

With the current declaration, not only do you have a `Category` in the cache instead of a `List<Category>` but you only have the last `Category` per key.

I suggest removing the `@CachePut` annotations and doing the collection updates in the cache yourself.

Note that this will need to be thread safe and that may require more thought.

Comment: thanks, I use `@CacheEvict` with `allEntries`, and I can get a list of categories.